# SELECT Mysql with combination of two where

Tags: mysql

I want select 2 Rows from the mysql table with additional "LIKE" and "AND" clauses.. 
Wit like clause I want to find only word starting with "a%"..
But I can't find the syntax error. Can you give me some hints.??

```
SELECT word,description
FROM word
WHERE(`language` = CONVERT( _utf8 'Tedi' USING armscii8 ) AND like 'a%')  AND `visible` =1
```

many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Koko

Comment: `... and language like ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is a missing expression before the `LIKE` comparison operator.

We'll have to guess what expression you wanted to do the comparison operation on, so I'll just choose the first column from the SELECT list, to demonstrate:

```
SELECT w.word
     , w.description
  FROM word w
 WHERE w.language = CONVERT( _utf8 'Tedi' USING armscii8 )
   AND w.word LIKE 'a%' 
   AND w.visible = 1
```

The predicates in the `WHERE` clause specify the criteria that a row has to satisfy before it will be returned, it doesn't care whether that's zero rows, two rows or a brazilian rows.